# How to get value of "Search Dialog" in jqgrid navGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to get value of "Search Dialog" in jqgrid navGrid.

But I don't know how to get it.

Example pic as follows

[example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOilS.jpg)

I have to get values.

**CREATEDATE

equal

2017-07-25**

I not only use 'eq' but use 'ne','lt'...etc.

(sopt : ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw'])

Versions:
 - jqGrid 5.1.1

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In which moment you want to get these values? - before to click the search, after click the search or..?

Comment: I set export function. According to these condition values, export data from mysql database. 
So I want to get these values when user click export button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read The [Guriddo jqGrid docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#single-search-options) You can get these values when using onSearch event. Since this is a single search dialog a [predefined fields are used](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#predefined-fields).

To get these values define the onSearch event like this

```
onSearch : function (filters) 
    postdata = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
    field = postdata.searchField;
    value = postdata.searchString;
    oper = postdata.searchOper;
    // return true to enable search, false to stop
    return true;
}
```

Note that this event should be defened within navigator searchoptions or as parameter in searchGrid method

Comment: Thank for Tony again ! I try to use your explanations in export function. I succeeded in getting these values. I think I should study Guriddo jqGrid docs seriously.

Comment: @Leo thanks, glad to help. For the export there is more easy way to do this. On button click you can add this code, suppose that url is the url send to the server `var params = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam","postData"); params = jQuery.param(params); if(url.indexOf("?") !== -1) { url = url+"&"+params; } else { url = o.url+"?"+params; } window.location = url;` At server you can check if a search is applied getting the parameter _search. If you have dificulties with this code I can post another answer for your requirment

Comment: Thanks your add comment. But it is litte difficult for me... I set a function and submit value to a hidden html form. The form includes php url.